# Is limiting About Section text input more beneficial or annoying?

Tags: input, text

**Background:** According to the study below (Found on NN), users read less than 1/4th of all text on a given webpage. So, theoretically, organizations would benefit from having much shorter about sections on social media sites and the like.

**Question:** Would having such limitations be helpful or annoying for the users inputting said information? They say good design is invisible, but I feel like limiting users in the way without providing justification could be problematic.

**Possible Solution?:** Would adding some explanation text in the form of a question mark/info icon + tooltip combo be worth it? Or is it still irritating for the user?

**Study:** http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1326561.1326566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still limit the required content on the page while seeming 'invisible' too.

People read online better in snippets or bullet points, so structure the input fields in a way that they will output in simple bullets.

[image]

This way you can control the volume of data entered, give the user some hints about what they can write and help structure the output content in a clean, sensible way.